# Sort random with must query Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I want to apply random sort based on **bool** query and want relevant results with random sorting.
Here is the query

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "random_score": {
        "seed": 100,
        "field": "_seq_no"
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "is_active": true
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "sentiment.keyword": [
                  "Negative",
                  "Sad"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "tag.keyword": [
                  "emotions",
                  "mental health",
                  "sadness"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tries using **random_score** but not sure is it helpful for me or not and anyone know usage of **seed**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function score query with `random_score` option.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": { "match_all": {} },
      "boost": "5",
      "random_score": {}, 
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

> The random_score generates scores that are uniformly distributed from
> 0 up to but not including 1. By default, it uses the internal Lucene
> doc ids as a source of randomness, which is very efficient but
> unfortunately not reproducible since documents might be renumbered by
> merges.
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-random

**In case you want scores to be `reproducible`, it is possible to provide a `seed` and field.** - do you need that?

Comment: Here we provide a number in seed can you please tell me the use of that?

Comment: Hey @SouravSinghGehlot, In case you want scores to be reproducible, it is possible to provide a seed and field. - **do you need that?**

Comment: No I don't want seed to be reproducible, So I will use it without seed
Thanks for help @Musab